# CSS Inclusion - Architect

Tags: sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

I have a project named Prototype which has a subdirectory(folder) named resources containing the folder css. In that particular css folder I have a  .css file which is exactly like the one in this fiddle :

http://new.senchafiddle.com/#/3qOhD/

How do i add it into my project with S.Architect 2.2.  I think I'm having difficulties with the url?

I have try this url : resouces/css/test.css

But when i write center_label in my labelcls it does not do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing an `r` in your url path. If you did correct this mistake then to add your custom `.css` file to your project:
 - Click the `+` icon at the top right of your `project inspector` and add a new resources (CSS resources to be specific). You should then see a new `css` resource listed under `Resources` under project inspector.
 - Give this `css` resource the path to your custom css file.

Comment: Thank you... feels like i have been doing too much today.